# How to write a test for nested JSON response from enterprise application

Tags: arrays, json, postman, postman-testcase

I'm trying to use Postman as a test tool to validate that our customers all have a mailing address in our master system.  I'm having trouble drilling down into the JSON due to its structure. Each response is an array structure with a single "node" that has no "head attribute" to address.

Example JSON:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "cmd_org_628733899",
    "organization": {
      "name": "FULL POTENTIAL",
      "accountStatusCode": "1",
      "accountStatusDescription": "OPEN"
    },
    "location": [
      {
        "locality": "LITTLE ROCK",
        "locationType": "MAILING"
      },
      {
        "locality": "BIG ROCK",
        "locationType": "LOCATION"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Test code as it exists:

```
pm.test("Check for a Mailing Address", function () {
   // Parse response body
   var jsonData = pm.response.json();

   // Find the array index for the MAILING Address
   var mailingLocationIndex = jsonData.location.map(
          function(filter) {
             return location.locationType; 
          }
    ).indexOf('MAILING'); 

   // Get the mailing location object by using the index calculated above
   var mailingLocation = jsonData.location[mailingFilterIndex];

   // Check that the mailing location exists
   pm.expect(mailingLocation).to.exist;

});
```

> Error message:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I understand that I have to iterate to node(0) in the outer array and then drill into the nested location array to find an entry with a locationType = Mailing.

I can't get past the outer array. I'm new to JavaScript and JSON parsing - I am a COBOL programmer.

Comment: Do you thing you could indent your code properly?

Comment: Sure - it lost it's formatting along the way. Apologies.

Comment: the brackets still do not match in the json example

Comment: Yes - just corrected that - the markup didn't like the [ on the same line as the ``` indicating code block.

Comment: please try again :)

Comment: So you have an array of items that *each* can have a mailing address. Your code is only for a single item that can have a mailing address (and possibly others types of address). What's your goal? Filter out all the items that have a mailing address?

Comment: The json will contain a single customer's information with an array of "location" data.  

I want identify if ANY of the entries in the "location" array have a locationType = "MAILING".

This is complicated from my perspective as the entire json is an array. I don't know how to address the 0 node.

I'm 99% sure my code would work if the json response wasn't an array.

Comment: That's a contradiction. You can't have both a "a single customer's information" and "the entire json is an array". Which one is it?

Comment: Please look at the revised corrected JSON.  The customer information is returned as an array with a single entry.

Comment: why not to use just jsonData[0] ?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That was the part I was missing - how to address/extract index(0) - so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing nothing else, I would say you mean this

```
pm.test("Check for a Mailing Address", function () {
    var mailingLocations = pm.response.json().location.filter(function (item) {
        return item.locationType === 'MAILING';
    });
    pm.expect(mailingLocations).to.have.lengthOf(1);
});
```

You want to filter out all the locations that have a `MAILING` type and there should be exactly one, or at least one, depending.

Whether `pm.response.json()` actually returns the object you show in your question is impossible to say from where I'm standing.

---

In modern JS, the above is shorter:

```
pm.test("Check for a Mailing Address", function () {
    var mailingLocations = pm.response.json().location.filter(item => item.locationType === 'MAILING');
    pm.expect(mailingLocations).to.have.lengthOf(1);
});
```

Comment: Sure!  Thanks again for helping answer my question and providing the modern JS code.